# Installing Azure authentication via composer on Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, azure, composer-php

So I purchased a laravel application but want to authenticate with Azure rather its current setup, I have found the ideal solution which is [metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth](https://github.com/metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth) the only issue is im not sure how to set this up and install it, I tried mapping to the local path in Windows Powershell and running `composer require metrogistics/laravel-azure-ad-oauth` I have both PHP and Composer installed but it returns with `error Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`

Would someone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong or install/configure the package for me? I'd be happy to pay a fee if someone could get it done and fully working (I'm happy configuring the Azure side, its just the web app side im struggling with)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include contents of your `composer.json`? The post-autoload-dump error relates with "extra" configuration for composer. The default entry in for laravel is "dont-discover". Where this is any different, package namespaces need to be properly configured